# Distorsion shader LUT for VROne lenses

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, shader, vrone

I am trying to create a shader that distorts and mirrors the video stream to  be seen by bifocal lenses as VROne.

VROne provides a unitypackage where I found the Look up Tables (LUT), that specify the distortion transformation.

We have a set of 6 lookup tables, 2 for each color.

[LUT_XB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCWzs.png), LUT_YB and also LUT_XG ,LUTYG , LUT_XR , LUT_YR. The result
is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or79o.png).

The Code provided by Zeiss:

```
//
// Copyright (C) 2014 - Carl Zeiss AG
//
// Distortion Shader
Shader "VROneSDK/LUTDistortion" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    // We have a set of LUTs.
    // for each color two. One for the x-direction
    // and one for the y-direction. _LUT<direction>Tex<Color>
    _LUTXTexR ("LUTXR", 2D) = "white" {}
    _LUTYTexR ("LUTYR", 2D) = "white" {}
    _LUTXTexG ("LUTXG", 2D) = "white" {}
    _LUTYTexG ("LUTYG", 2D) = "white" {}
    _LUTXTexB ("LUTXB", 2D) = "white" {}
    _LUTYTexB ("LUTYB", 2D) = "white" {}
}
SubShader {
    Pass {
        CGPROGRAM
        // We need to define a vertex shader even though
        // we don't use one.  Without this is an invalid
        // shader for GLES.
        #pragma target 3.0
        #pragma vertex vert_img
        // Fragement shader is function frag.
        #pragma fragment frag
        // Use unity
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"
        // We will use two variables _MainTex contains
        // the source texture
        uniform sampler2D _MainTex;

        // One Texture for each LUT (direction and color).
        uniform sampler2D _LUTXTexR;
        uniform sampler2D _LUTYTexR;
        uniform sampler2D _LUTXTexG;
        uniform sampler2D _LUTYTexG;
        uniform sampler2D _LUTXTexB;
        uniform sampler2D _LUTYTexB;

        // mirror flag for right eye (textures are for left
        // eye and mirrored for right eye)
        uniform bool _isMirrored;

        // Decoding a color value from the
        // texture into a float.  Similar to unitys
        // DecodeFloatRGBA and DecodeFloatRG.
        float DecodeFloatRGB(float3 rgb) {
            return dot(rgb, float3(1.0,1.0/255.0,1.0/65025.0));
        }

        float mirrored(float coord) {
            if (_isMirrored) {
                return 1.0f - coord;
            }
            return coord;
        }

        // compute new lookup position from a LUT.zz
        // For each color we extract the rgb value at the
        // coordinate we are interested in.  This rgb value
        // indicates which pixel (or interpolated pixel) we
        // need to map.
        float2 LUTDistortionR(float2 coord)
        {
            float3 lookupX = tex2D(_LUTXTexR, coord).rgb;
            float3 lookupY = tex2D(_LUTYTexR, coord).rgb;
            return float2(mirrored(DecodeFloatRGB(lookupX)),DecodeFloatRGB(lookupY));
        }

        float2 LUTDistortionG(float2 coord)
        {
            float3 lookupX = tex2D(_LUTXTexG, coord).rgb;
            float3 lookupY = tex2D(_LUTYTexG, coord).rgb;
            return float2(mirrored(DecodeFloatRGB(lookupX)),DecodeFloatRGB(lookupY));
        }

        float2 LUTDistortionB(float2 coord)
        {
            float3 lookupX = tex2D(_LUTXTexB, coord).rgb;
            float3 lookupY = tex2D(_LUTYTexB, coord).rgb;
            return float2(mirrored(DecodeFloatRGB(lookupX)),DecodeFloatRGB(lookupY));
        }

        float4 frag(v2f_img i) : COLOR
        {
            // our result will be initialized to 0/0/0.
            float3 res = float3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
            // Get the target (u,v) coordinate (i.uv)
            // which is where we will draw the pixel.
            // What we will draw, depends on the color
            // and the distortion, which we can look up in
            // the LUT.  We do this for each color and do
            // not put xy in rb or similar to allow us to
            // improve precision with the DecodeFloatRGB method,
            // as can be seen above.

            // since textures are for left eye only, we need to
            // "mirror" the input coordinate for the right eye.
            float2 coord = float2(mirrored(i.uv.x), i.uv.y);

            float2 xyR = LUTDistortionR(coord);
            if (xyR.x <= 0.0f || xyR.y <= 0.0f || xyR.x >= 1.0f || xyR.y >= 1.0f) {
                // set alpha to 1 and return.
                return float4(res, 1.0f);
            }

            float2 xyG = LUTDistortionG(coord);
            if (xyG.x <= 0.0f || xyG.y <= 0.0f || xyG.x >= 1.0f || xyG.y >= 1.0f) {
                // set alpha to 1 and return.
                return float4(res, 1.0f);
            }

            float2 xyB = LUTDistortionB(coord);
            if (xyB.x <= 0.0f || xyB.y <= 0.0f || xyG.x >= 1.0f || xyG.y >= 1.0f) {
                // set alpha to 1 and return.
                return float4(res, 1.0f);
            }

            res = float3(tex2D(_MainTex,xyR).r,
                         tex2D(_MainTex,xyG).g,
                         tex2D(_MainTex,xyB).b);

            // set alpha to 1 and return.
            return float4(res, 1.0f);
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

I want to create the fragment shader, that converts a stream of YUV frame (I created a sampler2D for each y, u, v : sampler2D s_texture_y...).

The code I implemented :

```
NSString *const vertexShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
   gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
   v_texcoord = texcoord.xy;
}

 );

NSString *const distortionVROneShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
precision highp float;

varying highp vec2 v_texcoord;

 uniform sampler2D s_texture_y;
 uniform sampler2D s_texture_u;
 uniform sampler2D s_texture_v;

 uniform sampler2D LUTXTexR;
 uniform sampler2D LUTYTexR;
 uniform sampler2D LUTXTexG;
 uniform sampler2D LUTYTexG;
 uniform sampler2D LUTXTexB;
 uniform sampler2D LUTYTexB;


 float DecodeFloatRGB(vec3 rgb) {
     return dot(rgb, vec3(1.0,1.0/255.0,1.0/65025.0));
 }


 vec2 LUTDistortionR(vec2 coord)
 {
    vec3 lookupX = texture2D(LUTXTexR, coord).rgb;
    vec3 lookupY = texture2D(LUTYTexR, coord).rgb;
    return vec2(DecodeFloatRGB(lookupX),DecodeFloatRGB(lookupY));
 }
 vec2 LUTDistortionG(vec2 coord)
 {
    vec3 lookupX = texture2D(LUTXTexG, coord).rgb;
    vec3 lookupY = texture2D(LUTYTexG, coord).rgb;
    return vec2(DecodeFloatRGB(lookupX),DecodeFloatRGB(lookupY));
 }
 vec2 LUTDistortionB(vec2 coord)
 {
    vec3 lookupX = texture2D(LUTXTexB, coord).rgb;
    vec3 lookupY = texture2D(LUTYTexB, coord).rgb;
    return vec2(DecodeFloatRGB(lookupX),DecodeFloatRGB(lookupY));
 }


 void main()
 {
    highp float y = texture2D(s_texture_y, v_texcoord).r * 1.0;
    highp float u = texture2D(s_texture_u, v_texcoord).r - 0.5;
    highp float v = texture2D(s_texture_v, v_texcoord).r - 0.5;


    highp float r = y +             1.402 * v;
    highp float g = y - 0.344 * u - 0.714 * v;
    highp float b = y + 1.772 * u;

    vec3 textureRGB = vec3(r,g,b);

    vec3 res = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);

    vec2 xyR = LUTDistortionR(v_texcoord);
    vec2 xyG = LUTDistortionG(v_texcoord);
    vec2 xyB = LUTDistortionB(v_texcoord);

   gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(s_texture_y, xyR).r,texture2D(s_texture_u,xyG).r,texture2D(s_texture_v, xyB).r,1.0);// vec4(res,1.0);
 }

 );
```

The result that I get with this code doesn't seem to distort the video stream, I suspect that the LUT importation as LUTXTexR, LUTXTexG, LUTXTexB ... should be done as a bufferSample.

I am stuck, any help, indication or link to tutorial is welcomed, as I couldn't find relevant tutorials for this specific application.